# Может ли функция быть частью "цепочки ссылок"?

Tags: javascript, функции, объекты, сборщик-мусора, root

Есть такой код:

```js
function f() {
    let a = 'some text';
    var obj1 = {};
    var obj2 = {};
    obj1.p = obj2; // obj1 references obj2
    obj2.p = obj1; // obj2 references obj1. This creates a cycle.
}
f();
```

После выполнения этой функции все ее внутренние объекты удаляются, вроде бы как потому что на них больше нет прерывается ссылок, идущих с `root`. Я немного не понимаю почему.

`function` по своей же сути тоже является объектом - это на мой взгляд создает "связь с root": функция объявлена в глобальном скоупе, в этой функции объявлены объекты.

Либо здесь другая логика: объекты только одного и того же типа могут образовывать "цепочку ссылок"? `Plain objects` могут быть в цепочке только с `plain objects`, `array` с `array` и т.д.

Comment: Локальные переменные не хранятся внутри объекта-функции. При вызове функции создаётся специальный вспомогательный служебный объект. Локальные переменные являются свойствами этого объекта. При повторном вызове функции служебный объект создаётся снова, но это уже _другой_ объект, не тот же самый, что был создан при предыдущем вызове. Если при завершении функции на этот служебный объект больше нет ссылок, то он уничтожается. А если есть, то он продолжает жить. Независимость функции-объекта от объекта, хранящего локальные переменные — ключевой элемент в таком явлении как _замыкания_.

Comment: @wololo кажется вы говорите про лексическое окружение? **Если при завершении функции на этот служебный объект больше нет ссылок, то он уничтожается.** - ссылка на этот объект (lexical environment) пропадает, как я понимаю, когда функция заканчивает свое выполнение, правильно?

Comment: Да, речь о лексическом окружении. Да, обычно, когда функция заканчивает своё выполнение, то больше ссылок на него нет. **Но** вы явно можете создавать ссылки на этот него с помощью замыканий. Пример: `function foo() {
 let a = 0;
 return function() {console.log(a++);}
}

let f = foo(); f(); f(); f(); f =null;` Функция `foo` закончила свою работу, но её лексическое окружение продолжает жить. Функция `f` имеет скрытое свойство — ссылку на лексическое окружение, _в котором она была создана_.  Только после потери ссылки на `f` (`f =null;`) окончательно теряется доступ к окружению `foo`.

Comment: @wololo Но тогда это противоречит тому, что написано на сайте [learn.javascript.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/garbage-collection): **Существует базовое множество достижимых значений, которые не могут быть удалены. Например: локальные переменные и параметры текущей функции, переменные и параметры других функций в текущей цепочке вложенных вызовов, глобальные переменные...**

Comment: @wololo Получается, что после того, как функция завершила свою работу, все, что находится в lexical environment удаляется - все переменные, параметры... Здесь же пишется, что, наоборот, параметры, переменные... никогда не удаляются.

Comment: Нет, не противоречит. «Существует базовое множество достижимых значений, которые не могут быть удалены. Например: локальные переменные и параметры **текущей** функции, переменные и параметры других функций в **текущей** цепочке вложенных вызовов, глобальные переменные...» Пока выполняется **текущая** функция, её лексическое окружение не может быть удалено, как и лексические окружения в **текущей** цепочке вызовов. `переменные... никогда не удаляются` В **текущей** цепочке вызовов.

Comment: @wololo хорошо. Получается, что после выполнения функции могут удалятся локальные переменные и параметры. **Ссылки на объекты и сами объекты - что с ними происходит?** Они очищаются вместе с "очисткой" `lexical environment` или их может очистить только сборщик мусора алгоритмом `Mark-and-sweep`? Что происходит с объектами, на каком этапе браузер понимает, что их тоже можно удалить?

Comment: Лексическое окружение — это и есть объект. А локальные переменные и параметры — его свойства. Как только лексическое окружение больше не доступно (мы не внутри функции, мы не воспользовались замыканиями), оно может быть удалено сборщиком мусора. `сами объекты - что с ними происходит?` То же, что и с лексическим окружением (а с лексическим окружением то же, что и с объектами) — как только объект становится недоступен, то в любой момент он может быть удалён сборщиком мусора.

Comment: @wololo то есть я понял, что после завершения работы функции удаляется все, что было в `lexical environment`, **кроме объекта**. После удаления всех переменных, которые были внутри `lexical environment`, браузер видит, что на объекты уже ничто не ссылается/не держит эту ссылку (так как `lexical environment` удален) - объект удаляется. Так?

Comment: Пусть есть функция `function f(){let a = 1, obj = {}; return 0}`. Пусть _условно говоря_ функция только закончила свою работу, и сборщик мусора ещё не сделал свою работу. У нас есть **два объекта**: 1) объект-«лексическое окружение», у которого два свойства — числовое и ссылка на пустой объект. 2) пустой объект. После завершения работы функции один из этих объектов ссылается на другой, **но** у нас доступа к этим объектам больше нет. Всё. В любой момент эта пара объектов может быть уничтожена сборщиком. Когда, в каком порядке и каким образом он это сделает — детали работы конкретного движка.

Comment: На самом деле у объекта-«лексического окружения» свойств не два, а больше: есть ещё `this`, есть `arguments`, но в рамках приведённого примера это не важно.

Comment: @wololo кажется я нашел ответ на свой вопрос. [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46281652/circular-referencing-in-javascript-reference-counting) пишется, что после окончания работы функции в `lexical environment` удаляются сначала переменные, а потом уже объекты (это что касается алгоритма подсчёта ссылок). Это хорошо объясняет "проблему циклических ссылок", которую я долго не мог понять.

Comment: @wololo В алгоритме **Mark-and-sweep** я думаю, что после окончания работы функции, сама функция прекращает ссылаться на объект `LE`, и соответственно он удаляется весь и сразу т.к. не может висеть просто в воздухе. Функция ссылается на `LE` только во время выполнения функции

Comment: @wololo Ну это что насчёт алгоритмов подсчёта ссылок и Mark-and-sweep. Сейчас же существуют новые алгоритмы, и за всех как они работают и устроены трудно сказать - вы правы)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Либо здесь другая логика: объекты только одного и того же типа могут
> образовывать "цепочку ссылок"? Plain objects могут быть в цепочке
> только с plain objects, array с array и т.д.

Последний абзац это чепуха, неизвестно откуда взявшаяся. Не будем об этом говорить.

---

Локальные переменные внутри функции живут только пока выполняется функция (и то - с оговорками). Они останутся в памяти, если ссылки на них каким-то образом выйдут из функции наружу, чего в Вашем случае не происходит. После того как функция отработала, она "не ссылается" на свои локальные переменные.

С другой стороны. Функция, как объект, может быть частью цепочки ссылок.

Comment: **После того как функция отработала, она не ссылается на свои локальные переменные.** то есть после отработки функции эта "цепочка ссылок", которая была, как я понимаю, разрывается потому что функция удаляет  все ссылки на свои внутренние объекты - следовательно, происходит удаление объекта. Правильно я вас понял?

Comment: @Ivan Не совсем. Функция может ничего не удалять. Сборка мусора спрятана внутри движка. Известно одно: объекты (и группы объектов, образующие кольцевые зависимости), на которые нет внешних ссылок, будут удалены из памяти.